# How to make blob represenation of a vector to Redis vector search (PHP)?

Tags: php, vector, redis

i've got vector [-0.00047102556, -0.0066432534, -0.029728396, ...]

Redis whats it to blob representation like \x12\xa9\xf5\x6c

How it can be done in PHP?

For python we have such solution

```
function float32Buffer(arr) {
  return Buffer.from(new Float32Array(arr).buffer);
}
```

Comment: Could you show how exactly?
In NumPy library it looks

Comment: like 
np.array(vector).astype(np.float32).tobytes()
but php analog "NumPhp" in packagist does not have such functionality

Comment: thanks a lot man!
Key Size: 28 KB
Length: 1
Now the size of the byte value in redis is 28kb
but there is not indexed records. I not know why 

FT.CREATE embedding SCHEMA vec VECTOR HNSW 6 TYPE FLOAT32 DIM 1536 DISTANCE_METRIC COSINE

index created but no indexed records when i hset them

Comment: the value of vector looks like \x7c\xfd\x17\xbc\x18\xf3\x20\x3c\x88\x0e\x99\xbc\x66\x4f\x18\xbc\xce\xc9\x34\xbc\xc7\x22\ and its apparently correct

Comment: Since redis is a key/value storage (afaik) are you probably mixing the term key and value? A key should be very short like an identifier, but the value may be longer containing the data.

Answer (score 0):

To get the binary data you can make use of the PHP [pack()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack) function.

The `f` format is used to encode as float.

```
$vector = [-0.00047102556, -0.0066432534, -0.029728396];
$blob = pack('f*', ...array_map('floatval', $vector));
```

To see the hex values use for example

```
echo bin2hex($blob);
```

Gives in this case

> fbf3f6b9a6afd9bbf788f3bc

Demo: https://3v4l.org/dqgbQ